# Incluir valores em único tabuleiro e mostra isso na tela sem precisar repetir os tabuleiros

Tags: python, while, jogos

Como eu faço para imprimir uma coordenada sem precisar imprimir vários tabuleiros com os valores que eu digitei no tabuleiro?

```
tabuleiro = [[0 for x in range(0, 10)] for o in range(0, 10)]
print('------------------')
print('   a | b | c |')
print('0 ', tabuleiro[0][0], '|', tabuleiro[0][1], '|', tabuleiro[0][2], '|')
print('1 ', tabuleiro[1][0], '|', tabuleiro[1][1], '|', tabuleiro[1][2], '|')
print('2 ', tabuleiro[2][0], '|', tabuleiro[2][1], '|', tabuleiro[2][2], '|')
print('------------------')
while True:
    coor = input('Informe sua coordenada: ')
    if coor == 'a0':
        tabuleiro[0][0] = coor
    elif coor == 'b0':
        tabuleiro[0][1] = coor
    elif coor == 'c0':
        tabuleiro[0][2] = coor
    elif coor == 'a1':
        tabuleiro[1][0] = coor
    elif coor == 'b1':
        tabuleiro[1][1] = coor
    elif coor == 'c1':
        tabuleiro[1][2] = coor
    elif coor == 'a2':
        tabuleiro[2][0] = coor
    elif coor == 'b2':
        tabuleiro[2][1] = coor
    elif coor == 'c2':
        tabuleiro[2][2] = coor
    print('------------------')
    print('   a | b | c |')
    print('0 ', tabuleiro[0][0], '|', tabuleiro[0][1], '|', tabuleiro[0][2], '|')
    print('1 ', tabuleiro[1][0], '|', tabuleiro[1][1], '|', tabuleiro[1][2], '|')
    print('2 ', tabuleiro[2][0], '|', tabuleiro[2][1], '|', tabuleiro[2][2], '|')
    print('------------------')
    
    COMO ESTÁ SENDO IMPRIMIDO!
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Opa, refiz aqui algumas coisa, dê uma estudada ai.

Sobre sua questão, você deve importar o método system da lib os, e mandar como argumento o comando cls que é o comando de limpar o prompt no Windows, esse método irá executar no prompt o que você passar pra ele.

```
from os import system  #Importa método system
from re import sub #Pega somente caracteres específicos 

def tabuleiro(x = None, y = None):  #Imprime tabuleiro
    tabuleiro = [[0 for x in range(0, 3)] for o in range(0, 3)]  #Gera novo tabuleiro
    system("cls") # Informa comando para prompt que limpa o mesmo

    if x != None:  #Verifica se houve movimento
        tabuleiro[x][y] = "X"  #Atribui X a matriz

    print('------------------')
    print('   0 | 1 | 2 |')
    print('0 ', tabuleiro[0][0], '|', tabuleiro[0][1], '|', tabuleiro[0][2], '|')
    print('1 ', tabuleiro[1][0], '|', tabuleiro[1][1], '|', tabuleiro[1][2], '|')
    print('2 ', tabuleiro[2][0], '|', tabuleiro[2][1], '|', tabuleiro[2][2], '|')
    print('------------------')

tabuleiro()  #Imprime tabuleiro
while True:
    coor = sub('[^0-9]', "", input("Informe sua coordenada (Linha/Coluna): "))  #Pega somente números 

    if not coor: #verifica se a variavel está vazia
        print("Preciso de um valor!")
        continue

    coorX = int(coor[0])  #Pega o indice 0 da string
    coorY = int(coor[1])  #pega o indice 1 da string

    if coorX >= 3 or coorY >= 3:  #Verifica se o valor é válido
        print("Opps, não dá pra ir ai")
    else:
        tabuleiro(coorX, coorY) #Atualiza posição
```

Abraço...

Answer (score -3):

Cara, eu não entendi muito bem o que você fez. Mas creio que você queria limpar a tela. Então é só dar o clear ou cls

Comment: Eu queria deixar o curso piscando em cada posição do tabuleiro a cada vez que fazer uma jogada sem precisar imprimir outro tabuleiro embaixo!